# Updating values with another table values using trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables!

PID

```
 P        ID
Jo Te     00001
Mo To     00002
Tim Fo    00003
```

NF0

```
 P2        NewID       Team
Jo Te         -       TeamC
Mo To         -       TeamV
Jo Te         -       TeamX
Tim Fo        -       TeamZ
```

I want to create a trigger that updates table NF0 if in table PID is inserted new  values! I wrote this trigger upd:

```
delimiter $$
Create trigger upd after insert on pid
 for each row begin
update nf0 set nf0.PID=new.iD ;
 end $$
```

,but it updates it like this!

NF0

```
 P2         NewID       Team
Jo Te      00003       TeamC
Mo To      00003       TeamV
Jo Te      00003       TeamX
Tim Fo        -        TeamZ
```

, but I want output to look like this

```
  P2        NewID       Team
Jo Te      00001       TeamC
Mo To      00002       TeamV
Jo Te      00001       TeamX
Tim Fo     00003       TeamZ
```

What I am writing wrong?

Comment: You missed the `where` clause and therefore updated all rows in nf0. Try `update nf0 set nf0.PID=new.iD where nf0.p2=new.p;`

Comment: returned all values '-' that is set default for NewID column

Comment: While I was typing, you edited the question and renamed columns. Now `update nf0 set NewID=new.ID where P2=new.P;` seems correct. Or do you want to _insert_ into `nf0`? Please post the desired output.

Comment: tried it still the same output! I want to update! Desired output will be given ! Just a minute!

Comment: Sorry for the question, but your order of steps is: 1) table PID is empty; 2) `create trigger...`; 3) `insert into PID...`; 4) `select * from nf0`?

Comment: Table PID is created from another table using trigger !

Comment: Ahaaaa! This is an important information. See [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html). Seems you should add `FOLLOWS other_trigger` then!

Comment: tried it it many ways shows error Error Code: 3011. Referenced trigger 'crt' for the given action time and event type does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
create table PID (
    P  char(10),
    ID char(10)
);

create table nf0 (
    P2    char(10),
    NewID char(10),
    Team  char(10)
);

insert into nf0 (P2,Team) values
    ('Jo Te',  'TeamC'),    
    ('Mo To',  'TeamV'),    
    ('Jo Te',  'TeamX'),    
    ('Tim Fo', 'TeamZ');

delimiter $$
create trigger upd after insert on PID
for each row
begin
    update nf0 set NewID=new.ID where P2=new.P;
end $$
delimiter ;

select * from nf0;

+--------+-------+-------+
| P2     | NewID | Team  |
+--------+-------+-------+
| Jo Te  | NULL  | TeamC |
| Mo To  | NULL  | TeamV |
| Jo Te  | NULL  | TeamX |
| Tim Fo | NULL  | TeamZ |
+--------+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

insert into PID (P,ID) values
    ('Jo Te',  '00001'),
    ('Mo To',  '00002'),
    ('Tim Fo', '00003');

select * from nf0;

+--------+-------+-------+
| P2     | NewID | Team  |
+--------+-------+-------+
| Jo Te  | 00001 | TeamC |
| Mo To  | 00002 | TeamV |
| Jo Te  | 00001 | TeamX |
| Tim Fo | 00003 | TeamZ |
+--------+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

From the OP's comments it got clear that the table PID gets filled by another trigger. So the trigger `upd` must be called *after* that other trigger. Let's assume the other trigger is called `fill_pid`, then

```
delimiter $$
create trigger upd after insert on PID 
for each row FOLLOWS fill_pid
begin
    update nf0 set NewID=new.ID where P2=new.P;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

will do.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I create table PID from another table using trigger or maybe problem is that instead of inserting values i upload them from csv file?

Comment: did not worked for  me! if inserted this part in my whole code! :(

Comment: @MārcisLiepiņš From the docs: _INSERT: The trigger activates whenever a new row is inserted into the table; for example, through INSERT, LOAD DATA, and REPLACE statements._ So CSV uploading is no problem, but I think the other trigger is. Try the `FOLLOWS ...` code.

Comment: Thank you @TinTran. Actually it was a +10 you gave me :-)

Comment: @MārcisLiepiņš I edited my answer (moved FOLLOWS... after `for each row`). Was wrong syntax before.

Comment: Still the same error 3011:Referenced trigger 'fill_pid' for the given action time and event type does not exist

Comment: Perhaps the other trigger is not an `AFTER INSERT` but a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger? Try `show triggers\G` (yes, with `\G` instead of `;`).

Comment: Both are after! and show triggers\g did not worked in script!

Comment: Maybe you can help with this question ! If this question would be answered i might not need this one to finish code! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847260/how-to-make-primary-key-update-its-one-column

Comment: Ok, this `\G` thing works only in mysql client. In the comment above you/your MySQL complained about `fill_pid`. You must give _your_ trigger's name, not my one. ;-)

Comment: I renamed It before that comment! :)

Comment: What MySQL version do you have? Before 5.7.2 the FOLLOWS/PRECEDS do not work. Docs: _Before MySQL 5.7.2, there cannot be multiple triggers for a given table that have the same trigger event and action time._

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter $$
Create trigger upd after insert on pid
 for each row begin
update nf0 set nf0.P2=new.iD 
where nf0.P2 = new.P;
 end $$
```